# Filtering out duplicates when

Tags: mysql

I have a list with column `increment_id` and column `product_type`. Now I want to filter out all duplicates for `increment_id` but this should only be done for rows with "simple" in the `product_type` collumn.

Comment: have you tried using `'DISTINCT'` or `'GROUP BY'` or `'ORDER BY'` in your MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `increment_id` from `table` WHERE `product_type` = 'simple';
```

This will select the unique `increment_id`s from rows where `product_type` is "simple"

Comment: This could be correct but having duplicates in a column called 'increment_id' sounds awful. I think the OP should look at why he has duplicate id's in their table to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want other rows too.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `increment_id` from `table` WHERE `product_type` = 'simple'
UNION ALL
SELECT `increment_id` from `table` WHERE `product_type` <> 'simple';
```

Answer (score 0):

okay heres the thing:

i join my sales_flat_order with my sales_flat_order_item. so for every order (increment_id) i have multiple rows in the sales_flat_order_item. so thats why i get duplicates for increment_id.

Besides i **dont** want to have the duplicates of increment_id with product_type = simple in my results.